# How to save a data to nested document

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a data structure that looks like this:

```
users > {user-auto-id} > network > {network-auto-id}
```

I m not sure how I can add entries to the network. I m updating a document of users like the following which is working fine

```
const captureCol = collection(
  firestore,
  'users'
);

const docToUpdate = doc(myCol, 'id123');
  const udata: any = {
    title: 'title',
  };
  if (data.testExecutionLinkData) {
    delete udata.testExecutionLinkData;
  }

await updateDoc(docToUpdate, udata);
```

I tried to get the reference of the nested document like this, but it's failing

```
docToUpdate.collection('network1'); // ERROR: collection is not a function
```

Comment: as you said that is a nested doc.You need to give the complete path of that nested doc

Comment: How I can do that?

Comment: thx, it worked with creating a doc ref like `const doc1 = doc(myCol, 'id123', 'network1', 'h3cg5kCB2blz4rxdImUd');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting an error when using:

```
docToUpdate.collection('network1');
```

Because you're creating a collection reference and not a document reference. To solve this, you have to create a reference that points exactly to the document you need to be updated. In code it should look like this:

```
db.collection('users').doc('user-auto-id').collection('network').doc('network-auto-id')
```

And right after that perform the update.